# Unable to block/bypass the user prompt when trying to import self signed CA certificate into Windows Root Truststore using Java KeyStore class

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

Unable to block/bypass the user prompt when trying to import self signed CA certificate into Windows Root Trust store using Java KeyStore class

I have generated self signed Root CA X509Certificate successfully. Now Since it is a self signed certificate, I want to import it into the Windows Root Trust store (Trusted Root Certification Authority) from Java. While I tried to import the certificate from Java using Keystore class into the Windows-ROOT, the Java code runs but there is a prompt where we need to trust and accept the import by clicking on "YES". How can we prevent or bypass this prompt to accept this certificate import popup and directly import the certificate without any user action?

I tried the same code to import the certificate into Windows-MY "Personal" truststore and I do not get any pop up user prompt. The certificate is imported into Personal truststore from Java successfully. Similarly I want to import the certificate into Windows-ROOT too without any user prompt. Kindly help.

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT", "SunMSCAPI");
keyStore.load(null, null);  // Load keystore

keyStore.setCertificateEntry("AliasNameExample", x509Certificate);
keyStore.store(null, null);
```

Using Java code how can we import the self signed CA certificate into Windows Root truststore without getting prompted for user input to accept "Yes/No".

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bypass this prompt dialog. It is embedded in the crypt32.dll library (`CertAddCertificateContextToStore` function).

The only workaround is to use Local Machine store. However, it requires full administrator permissions.

Comment: Whenever I tried to import the certificate, it is always imported into the CURRENT_USER. What changes should I make to the above Java code to import the certificate into LOCAL MACHINE? Also will this work around of importing into Local Machine store prevent the pop up when I run it with full Admin rights?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java API. But if you can figure it out how to install the certificate in local machine store, the popup will not appear. But the application must be executed in elevated mode with full administrator permissions.